# How to trigger analyticsInteraction aura component from Lightning web components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-community, lightning-web-components

How to trigger analyticsInteraction aura component from Lightning web components?
Below is the code to trigger analyticsInteraction using aura component

```
var analyticsInteraction = $A.get("e.forceCommunity:analyticsInteraction");
    analyticsInteraction.setParams({
        hitType : 'event',
        eventCategory : 'Button',
        eventAction : 'click',
        eventLabel : 'Winter Campaign Button',
        eventValue: 200
    });
    analyticsInteraction.fire();
}
```

Can we do the same as above using Lightning web component?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no equivalent for the `analyticsInteraction`. According to the document below are the supported events as of today.

This [**table**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.migrate_events) maps standard Aura events, such as for navigating to a component or to display the record create panel, to usage in Lightning web components. Events that are not listed don’t currently have an equivalent in Lightning Web Components.

[image]